# Transfering demo magento shop to old magento and connect with the database

Tags: magento-1.9, database, server-setup, link

I am working on a magento website from client and I am not a coder, this is my first magento website. I know it sounds confusing just by looking at the title, so let me elaborate you on this.

1. I got a new theme installed on my website (http://design.inpro.com.my), I have done all required and its time to migrate it.
2. My client wanted me to migrate the new theme from my website to their existing website (http://gogoonline.com.my).
3. They already have a website running on magento with all the orders and customers data.

   - What they want is, migrate the new theme to their website, but link the existing customer and order/ products database to this new theme.
   - How can I do this? Is there any step by step tutorial available online?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are only transferring the theme and not the database or store settings. 
Assuming all the modules required for your new theme to work are already installed on the old site.

Step 1: Put your site on maintenance or disable it temporarily 
Step 2: Disable the Magento Cache 
System ->Cache Management (select all and Disable) 
Step 3: Copy your theme files from the following locations 
app/design/frontend/{{package_name}}/{{theme_name}}
skin/frontend/{{package_name}}/{{theme_name}}
to the the old site.
If your theme uses any JS files from /js copy them to the old site as well
Step 4: To see the theme applied you will have to configure magento to use your newly  installed theme and package go to System -> Configuration ->general ->Design 
and fill in the appropriate data for Package and Theme.

Step 5: Test your theme once your happy with the result, take it off maintenance and enable all the cache.